# jQuery only "this". Easy question

Tags: jquery, this

I am just stuck in one simple jQuery question. 
I am trying to each `span` element prependTo `p` element, but jQuery is repeating each span 3 times (because I have 3 span elements). Ok it is hard to explain.

**Just look at Fiddle code - http://jsfiddle.net/fTjcy/1/**

HTML:

```
<div class="events">

<div class="event">
<span class="red">31.08.11  - </span>
<p>...</p>

</div> <!-- END OF New -->



<div class="event">
<span class="red">28.08.2011  - </span><p>...</p>
</div> <!-- END OF New -->



<div class="event">
<span class="red">20.08.2011  - </span><p>...</p>
</div> <!-- END OF New -->

</div>
```

I wanna achieve :

```
<div class="events">

<div class="event">

<p><span class="red">31.08.11  - </span>...</p>
</div> <!-- END OF New -->



<div class="event">
<p><span class="red">28.08.2011  - </span>...</p>
</div> <!-- END OF New -->



<div class="event">
<p><span class="red">20.08.2011  - </span>...</p>
</div> <!-- END OF New -->

</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$('.event span.red').hide().prependTo('.event p').show();
```

Comment: And what is it that you want to achieve?

Comment: You should update your fiddle too. The HTML there does not fit the HTML in the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to target the current `span` only, and prepend it to the relative `p` only.

```
var p = $('.event p');

$('.event span.red').hide().each(function(i) {
    $(this).prependTo( p[ i ] ).show();
});
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/fTjcy/3/

Comment: Or, if the structure stays like this: `$(this).prependTo($(this).next()).show();`

Comment: @Felix: Well, it depends on if OP is using the structure in the jsFiddle, or the one now posted in the question. The fiddle has one of  the `p` elements nested in a `div` which is the sibling to the `span`. EDIT: I see now from your comment under the question that you noticed that too.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('.event span.red').hide().each(function(i) {
    $(this).prependTo($('.event p').eq(i)).show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.event span.red').each(function() {
    var paragraph = $(this).closest('.event').find('p');
    $(this).hide().prependTo(paragraph).show();
});
```